# Is there any way to not allow to use self server cert in nginx?

Tags: nginx, https, ssl-certificate

I would like to forbid to use self-signed server certificate in nginx on Windows.
Is there any way to do it?
I checked the nginx manual. But I couldn't find the way.

Comment: nginx on windows is weird enough. Still, it's not clear what do you want to forbid.

Comment: Do you want to set up nginx so it is impossible for sysadmins to use self signed certificates on the server side?